In which sense is this a proof of naturality?
In Introduction to Categories and Categorical Logic by Abramsky et al., it is mentioned that the Currying operation $\Lambda$, used in defining exponentials, defines a natural bijection:
$$ \dfrac{f : A \times B \to C}{\Lambda (f) : A \to C^B} $$
It then goes on to prove that, for any $f : A \times B \to C$ and $g : A' \to A$: $$\Lambda (f) \circ g = \Lambda (f \circ (g \times id_B))$$
saying that this provides a proof of naturality of $\Lambda$.
I don't see how this is the case. Furthermore, in this MSE answer I found the following:

the existence of a bijection between the hom-sets
$$ \mathrm{Hom}(X\times Y,Z) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(X,Z^Y)$$
which is natural in both $X$ and $Z$

So I'm also confused on which naturality of the isomorphism the above statement should prove. I'm guessing naturality on $A$, but I still do not see why that should be the case.

It shows naturality in $A$, yes. As for how it does this, fit $\operatorname{Hom}(A, C^B)$, $\operatorname{Hom}(A \times B, C)$, $\operatorname{Hom}(A', C^B)$, $\operatorname{Hom}(A' \times B, C)$, $\Lambda$, $g^$ and $(g \times \mathrm{id}_B)^$ into the obvious naturality square and think about how the given equation precisely captures its commutativity  (and report back with details if you get stuck :).

You see the "$g\times1_B$" there? $g\times1_B$ is the value of $(-)\times B$ on the morphism $g$; that tells you you should think about naturality w.r.t variation in  $A$, and indeed the equation tells you that the following diagram commutes: $$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}\hom(A\times B,C)@>\cong>>\hom(A,C^B)\\@V(-)\circ(g\times1_B)VV@VV-\circ gV\\\hom(A'\times B,C)@>>\cong>\hom(A',C^B)\end{CD}$$Which says the isomorphisms are natural w.r.t the "variable" $A,A'$ and morphisms $g$ between them. Notice $\hom(-,C^B)$'s functor structure is given by precomposition, and $\hom(-\times B,C)=\hom(-,C)\circ(-)\times B$'s functor structure really does take $g$ to $g\times1_B$ to $(-)\circ(g\times1_B)$, so this really is a naturality diagram of functors.
So, it turns out that the canonical currying $\hom(X\times Y,Z)\cong\hom(X,Z^Y)$ is natural in all three variables. This is an instance of what Mac Lane calls a "parametric adjunction" or "parametrised adjunction" in "Categories for the Working Mathematician". These are very important; I personally call these fully natural adjunctions to emphasise the isomorphisms are natural in every single variable. Here, the "parameter" would be $Y$; for all $Y$, I obtain a pair of adjoint functors $(-)\times Y\dashv(-)^Y$, and the natural structure of a functor (in $Y$!) on the left hand side induces a functorial structure on $Z^Y$  (in $Y$!) such that the adjunction is fully natural.
